# Acessing divs using the selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, iframe

New to selenium and this is my sample project.

I have a element inside of a div that I cant access, I have tried searching for answers but only found java code. As I am new to selenium I am using the Table way of making my tests.

I found this answer:

You can use cssSelector,

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Fill Quote']")));

But there is no command called driver.

Sorry if this sounds stupid but my only wish is to learn!

Answer (score 1):

The 'driver' here is an instance standing for browser.
And you are finding elements by: browser.find_element_by...()

The steps of using selenium is actually same as the steps that you manually find elements on browser:

1. open a browser and enter URL

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

2. find elements by either id, class, tag or compound of them:

```py
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[title='Fill Quote']")
```

Here is a [doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html) for selenium of python.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where would i put this code as there is only 3 boxes. command, target and value.

Comment: my code is in python, it is just for illustrate the idea, if you want to run it. you can refer to the doc to learn more.